# Continuity of integer part function of $1/x^3$

Tags: calculus, analysis

> Check the continuity of $$f(x)=\left[\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right]\mathrm{Sgn}\big(\sin(\pi x/2)\big)$$ where $[\cdots]$ is the integer part of $\dfrac{1}{x^3}$

Is there someone who knows the answer?

Comment: Hi, user77711, please see if my edit is what you meant to write.

Comment: Is ${\rm sgn}\sin\pi/2$ supposed to be constant or is there an $x$ missing? And, have you tried graphing the function to get an idea of what the answer might be?

Comment: I've put in an $x$ since that's almost certainly what was meant. However, I'm still unsure whether that $\mathrm{Sgn}$ should be there... The question looks much more likely without that. Could the homophone have caused problems?